# What must I do to stop being distracted at my work and playing on my phone?

Tags: work-environment, productivity, work-time, phone, distractions

I keep on scrolling on my phone at work and it's an open work so people notice. Luckily, nobody told me off yet and probs never will since I am an intern and will leave soon. However, for my next job, I hope to convert my internship and become a full-time analyst ...what can I do to stop my behaviour?

What do I do when I am bored at work?

Comment: Why are you bored at work? Done with all the tasks?

Comment: Yes, I am not given many tasks. Basically, this firm is v. small and nobody has the time to manage me/give me more jobs. So I am left with either a small amount of work or easy admin tasks. Also, the person responsible for giving me work purposely gives me the most boring tasks ever since she is afraid of getting replaced

Comment: I was on contract once and while the macro processed the data I read the software manuals... valid use of time as I improved my skills for the work needed for the company.

Answer (score 3):

**Go make trouble**

I'm *partially* serious here. If you are being assigned a limited number of tasks and you are able to plow through them in a fraction of your work day - go look for something in the business that needs to be done and start doing it.

Now, if what you are doing isn't helping or making things worse - no one can fault your initiative - you can talk with your management and say that you are being underutilized and that you saw an issue and decided to take ownership to fix it - then you can have the conversation about increasing your workload or getting someone to help train you up on other tasks

Or...

What you are doing does help and you get to reap all that wonderful kudos.

**Training/UpSkilling**

Find something related to the industry that you've got an interest in and start learning. That way, if anyone raises it, you have a legitimate work-reason for doing what you're doing. If they aren't happy with this, again - you have the conversation about being under-utilized.

Comment: And I highly recommend deleting distracting apps from your phone, and deleting stored links and passwords for distracting websites. Anything that makes using them a bit more of a hassle gives you a chance to stop before you get sucked in. If necessary, power down the phone

Answer (score 1):

Instead of playing with a phone, start studying to improve your skills. There are plenty of ways to learn online and many different ways to improve.

Answer (score 1):

A [smartwatch](https://twellmall.com/) can reduce the amount of time you look at your phone. In my opinion, most of the time I look at my phone is to see if there are any new messages. Anyway, this is my case. Smart watches can receive notifications from phone calls, social software, messages, etc. This might help you focus on your work.